# Is typescript capable of accessing non-common fields of unions without type-guards?

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

Given

````
type union = { a: string, b: number, c: string, d: number } | {a: string, b: number, c: number } | {a: string, b: string }```
````

I'd like some working syntax similar to (the below does not compile ofc)

```
  const foo: union = ...;

  foo.a // : string
  foo.b // : number | string
  foo.c // : string | number | undefined
  foo.d // : number | undefined
  foo.e // : either compiler error (or never)
```

The compiler should already have the info for constructing these anonymous types, the question is whether some syntax exists for this.

Comment: "Is typescript capable of accessing non-common fields of unions without type-guards?" close, it would be more accurate to say "Typescript cannot access the non-common fields of a union without *discriminating the union*". Trying to access c, d, or e without doing so [will fail at compile time](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0VAvFA3lAhgFxQDOwATsogOYA0UARsYgK4C2DE59AxsWZRr0AJs3adyUAL5QAPriKkKVOozEcuvdROlyF-ZULVLB1aQFgAUFYBmLRD2BoMNgBQ3UqYnCTOAlLhWUFAeqAB0+ADcQSGeYQzRlsGhYTyJyXHC6bHhEIlSVkA). That answers the title, I can't tell what you're asking in the body?

Comment: Of course in the current form it will fail, that's why I'm asking whether there is a trick, or some alternative syntax that achieves what I'm asking for.

Comment: You haven't told us what you're trying to achieve... (Your question title reads like "Is TypeScript capable of _magic_?") - and what do you mean by "construction these anonymous types"? Do you mean you want to use `typeof` in a `type` declaration?

Comment: There's no compiler option to allow for accessing properties which potentially don't exist on a strictly typed value (even though it's a common pattern in JavaScript). [Here's a playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2QnYW) with your existing code. [Here's one](https://tsplay.dev/NBYppw) which demonstrates declaring all of the union members as having the same keys so that discrimination is not necessary. The "non-properties" are defined as `never` using the [_optional_ modifier (`?`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties). Does that satisfy your question?

Comment: I've been thinking about this last night. I think what I'm looking for is basically a type mapper from `type Foo = { a : string, b: number } | {a: string, b: string, c: string}` into `type MFoo = { a: string, b: number | string, c: string | undefined }`. I don't think this is magic, the compiler has all the information to be able to make that mapping. The use case is that I have a set of API typings generated by an outside tool, and would like an easy way to process it. Also in some cases determining the exact case of the sumtype is not possible/hard, of two different cases have similar props.

Comment: One more concrete example of a use case is error processing, each variant MAY have a different error type, with different fields, but some of the variants (not all) have a "message" field. I'd like to uniformly handle any returned errors that have a message field by say logging to the console for debugging purposes, and not care about the rest of fields. One way would be to cast to any, but the compiler SHOULD be able to coerce something like `x?!.error?!.message` to `string | undefined`